# Wired connection cannot be established - no eth0

Tags: networking, 14.04, wired

i am on ubuntu trusty 14.04, and i recently lost my wired ethernet connection for uknown reason.
I get eth0 no such device and other related errors.
I tried many solutions from other posts, and i probably messed up things more.
I also removed /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules and i tried to regenerate with no luck
Right now, my networking is always disabled and i am not able to enable.

Notice that is a dual boot, and i do connect perfectly fine in my old windows installation.

Below i attach some outputs i guess will be useful.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
tania@tania:~$ ifconfig -a
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:202 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:202 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:15228 (15.2 KB)  TX bytes:15228 (15.2 KB)

tania@tania:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp


tania@tania:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for tania: 
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:de00(size=256) memory:fbcff000-fbcfffff memory:fbcf8000-fbcfbfff
```

Comment: Does it enable with: sudo modprobe r8169 and then: ifconfig? If not, look for errors here and post them: dmesg | grep r8169 Thanks.

Comment: Please see permanent fix in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the driver module is not loading on boot. Let's try to fix it. In a terminal:

```
sudo -i
echo r8169  >>  /etc/modules
exit
```

Reboot and let us have your report.